# Count occurrence of array elements

Tags: arrays, matlab

Well I have an array called `A`:

```
[8 2
6 1
6 1
6 1
1 2]
```

How to count the occurrence of the same rows? It does not work well with `unique` because it does not differentiate between the rows.

Comment: Could you give the expected output for this example? Obviously Divakar understood your question in a different way than I did.

Comment: @Daniel Guess I was mistaken, so had to change my codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unique` to get the indices.

```
[R,ixb,ix]=unique(A,'rows')
```

Then use `histc` to count them

```
O=histc(ix,1:numel(ixb))
```

R contains the (unique) rows and O the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 3):

[`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) approach:

```
>> sparse(A(:,1), A(:,2), 1)
ans =
   (6,1)        3
   (1,2)        1
   (8,2)        1
```

If you need it in the form of two variables as in [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23703541/2586922):

```
[ii jj Occurrences] = find(sparse(A(:,1), A(:,2), 1));
Rows = [ii jj];
```

which gives

```
Rows =
     6     1
     1     2
     8     2

Occurrences =
     3
     1
     1
```

Answer (score 0):

One `bsxfun`+`unique` approach -

```
binmat1 = squeeze(all(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(A,[3 2 1])),2))
[~,ind1] = unique(bi2de(binmat1),'stable')
uniqueA = A(ind1,:)
counts = sum(binmat1(ind1,:),2)
```

Thus, if you have A as:

```
A=[ 8 2;
    6 1;
    6 1;
    6 1;
    1 2;
    63 1;
    63 1]
```

Output would be:

```
uniqueA =
     8     2
     6     1
     1     2
    63     1

counts =
     1
     3
     1
     2
```